# Does there exist a topology $\tau$ on $X \times Y$ such that $\Pi_x$ or $\Pi_y$ is not continuous

Tags: general-topology, projection

Does there exist a topology $\tau$ on $X \times Y$ such that $\Pi_x$ or $\Pi_y$ is not continuous where $\Pi_x$ is the projection of $X \times Y$ on $X$ and $\Pi_y$ is the projecion of $X \times Y$ on $Y$?

By the definition of product topology $\tau'$ on $X \times Y$ we see that it is the smallest topology on $X \times Y$ such that the projection map $\Pi_x , \Pi_y$ are continuous.

I have not come across any topology such that the projection  maps are not continuous.Does there exists such a topology?

Comment: Simply let the topology on ,$X \times Y$ be the topology where the only open sets are the entire set and the empty set. Then if $X$ or $Y$ does not have the trivial topology the projections will not be continuous.

Comment: If a function $f:A\to B$ is not constant then we can "make" the function discontinuous. This e.g. by letting $A$ be equipped with indiscrete topology and $B$ with discrete topology.

Comment: If we take the box topology on an arbitrary cartesian product of spaces then the projection map may not be necessarily continuous right?

Comment: @ThirstForMaths no, it must be continuous